# Name of Teacher with Highest Wage - recursive CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the max salary of each dept and display that teacher by first name as a separate column. So dept 1 may have 4 rows but one name showing for max salary. I'm Using SQL SERVER

```
With TeacherList AS(
Select Teachers.FirstName,Teachers.LastName,
Teachers.FacultyID,TeacherID, 1 AS LVL,PrincipalTeacherID AS ManagerID
FROM dbo.Teachers 
WHERE PrincipalTeacherID IS NULL

UNION ALL

Select Teachers.FirstName,Teachers.LastName,
Teachers.FacultyID,Teachers.TeacherID, TeacherList.LVL + 
1,Teachers.PrincipalTeacherID
FROM dbo.Teachers 
INNER JOIN TeacherList ON Teachers.PrincipalTeacherID = 
TeacherList.TeacherID
WHERE Teachers.PrincipalTeacherID IS NOT NULL)
SELECT * FROM TeacherList;
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT :

Teacher First Name |  Teacher Last Name | Faculty| Highest Paid In Faculty

---

```
  Eric              Smith               1          Eric
  Alex              John                1          Eric
  Jessica           Sewel               1          Eric 
  Aaron             Gaye                2          Aaron
  Bob               Turf                2          Aaron
```

Comment: Show the expected output for a sample data

Comment: Teacher First Name |  Teacher Last Name | Faculty| Highest Paid In Faculty

Comment: Do you want just the teacher with the highest pay in faculty?

Comment: Yes. per faculty i just want to show the teacher with highest salary in separate column but still with my CTE see my sample output

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: sql server and sms

Comment: @Derek Then add SQL Server tag.  Don't make us guess which dbms you are using.

Comment: READ THE QUESTION its in my question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from your description but this will return all teachers and the last row is the name of the teacher with the highest pay on the faculty.

```
select tr.FirstName,
       tr.LastName,
       tr.FacultyID,
       th.FirstName
from Teachers tr
join (
  select FacultyID, max(pay) highest_pay
  from Teachers 
  group by FacultyID
) t on tr.FacultyID = t.FacultyID
join Teachers th on th.FacultyID = t.FacultyID and
                    th.pay = t.highest_pay
```

this will produce an unexpected result (duplicate rows) if there are more persons with the highest salary on the faculty. In such case you may use window functions as follows:

```
select tr.FirstName,
       tr.LastName,
       tr.FacultyID,
       t.FirstName
from Teachers tr
join
(       
    select t.FirstName,
           t.FacultyID
    from 
    (
      select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by FacultyID order by pay desc) rn
      from Teachers t
    ) t
    where t.rn = 1
) t on tr.FacultyID = t.FacultyID
```

This will display just one random teacher from faculty with highest salary.

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=153c6455bf9e36801e61719370ea1b88)

Comment: is this suppised to be my select statement at the very end of the recursive cte? ie

Comment: @Derek no instead of it

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `CROSS APPLY`.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, FacultyID, HighestPaid
FROM Teachers t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 FirstName AS HighestPaid
             FROM Teachers
             WHERE FacultyID = t.FacultyID
             ORDER BY Salary DESC) ca
```